# How do I select all of the nodes in an xml file between two tags, depending on attribute name of the tag?

Tags: c#, xml, dom, xpath

I want to select all of the nodes in between the group tags where it has the name I want but I am unsure of how to do this. Below is an example where I would want to select every node where the group has the name "DefaultSettings".

```
<group name="DefaultSettings">
    <tag></tag>
    <tag></tag>
    <tag></tag>
    <tag></tag>
    <tag></tag>
    <tag></tag>
</group>

<group name="NewSettings">
    <tag></tag>
    <tag></tag>
    <tag></tag>
    <tag></tag>
    <tag></tag>
    <tag></tag>
</group>
```

I am currently trying to use the XmlDocument object to select all of the nodes but I am unsure of how to get Xpath to work properly as I don't want to select the other group with the name NewSettings. Any advice on what Xpath formula to use or any other way would be appreicated.

Edit: I have solved this by a combination of using  freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html and just general messing around. Sorry that I didn't research it as much as I thought I did but XPath is pretty confusing and now I know a lot more about how to use it.

Comment: Not will-researched...use this https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html and this https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

Comment: you mean `//group[@name='DefaultSettings']/node()`?

Comment: See my edit for response

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your XML

```
<groups>
   <group name="DefaultSettings">
      <tag />
      <tag />
      <tag />
      <tag />
      <tag />
      <tag />
   </group>
   <group name="NewSettings">
      <tag />
      <tag />
      <tag />
      <tag />
      <tag />
      <tag />
   </group>
</groups>
```

You can try something like this:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(str);  // suppose that str string contains "<groups>...</groups>"

XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/groups/group[@name='DefaultSettings']");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
  Console.WriteLine(xn.InnerText);
}
```